# How do I crop a TIFF down to a specific region?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I have two TIFFs that have the same pixel size. One of them is geolocated inside the other. I would like to crop the larger one down to the exact same extent as the smaller one. Is this possible with a gdal command?

```
gdalinfo small.tif
Pixel Size = (0.100000000000000,-0.100000000000000)
Upper Left  (-13042354.590, 3866165.781) (117d 9'41.27"W, 32d46'48.73"N)
Lower Left  (-13042354.590, 3865668.981) (117d 9'41.27"W, 32d46'35.22"N)
Upper Right (-13041857.790, 3866165.781) (117d 9'25.21"W, 32d46'48.73"N)
Lower Right (-13041857.790, 3865668.981) (117d 9'25.21"W, 32d46'35.22"N)
Center      (-13042106.190, 3865917.381) (117d 9'33.24"W, 32d46'41.98"N)

gdalinfo big.tif
Pixel Size = (0.100000000000000,-0.100000000000000)
Upper Left  (-13042373.699, 3866184.891) (117d 9'41.89"W, 32d46'49.25"N)
Lower Left  (-13042373.699, 3865649.891) (117d 9'41.89"W, 32d46'34.70"N)
Upper Right (-13041838.699, 3866184.891) (117d 9'24.59"W, 32d46'49.25"N)
Lower Right (-13041838.699, 3865649.891) (117d 9'24.59"W, 32d46'34.70"N)
Center      (-13042106.199, 3865917.391) (117d 9'33.24"W, 32d46'41.98"N)
```

Comment: If I read this right then `small.tif` above is actually the larger one? Also I've tried to recreate rasters using the coords printed but due to precision its not exact so the rasters don't match any more. Can you give the number of cells in X and Y also? And have you tried `gdal_translate` with `-projwin`? Or does the problem also involve a) finding which is the smaller and b) extracting the coordinates to pass to `-projwin`?

Comment: Sorry, I had `small.tif` and `big.tif` swapped around. I want to cut the extend of `small.tif` out of `big.tiff` and create a new tiff. @Spacedman

Comment: This is exactly what `gdal_translate -projwin` does, so unless you want to automate it for any two given TIFs, cut and paste the coordinates from `gdalinfo` for `small.tif` into a `gdal_translate` operation on `big.tif`.

Answer (score 1):

The `gdal_translate` command has a `-projwin` argument for selecting a window in projected coordinates:

```
-projwin ulx uly lrx lry
```

This needs upper left and lower right coordinates which you get from `gdalinfo`:

```
Upper Left  (-13042354.590, 3866165.781) (117d 9'41.27"W, 32d46'48.73"N)
Lower Right (-13041857.790, 3865668.981) (117d 9'25.21"W, 32d46'35.22"N)
```

So the full command would be:

```
gdal_translate -projwin -13042354.590 3866165.781 -13041857.790 3865668.981 big.tiff small_size_big.tiff
```

note the coordinates are space-separated.